# why i'm having problems with scanf and gets?

Tags: c, scanf

when i'm trying to use scanf and gets, i'm having trouble, i need to put gets twice, if i put it once my program is terminated, it's homework and i have to use those functions in those places.

the code :

```
int main()  
{
    int i=0,operation=0;
    char str[100];

    printMenu();

    scanf("%d",&operation);

    switch (operation)
    {
        case 1:     
            printf("Please, enter your sentence >");
            gets(str);
            gets(str);

            if (checkChars(str))
                inputSent(str);
            else
                printf("ERROR: Incorrect data, try again.");

            break;
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What could possibly go wrong using `gets` ?

Comment: Are you sure you're not having trouble with CheckChars() or inputSent()?

Answer (score 1):

So, we have a stdin stream of data. This is the input that you write at the terminal.

When you call `scanf`, it only reads the decimal number that you wrote. It does not read the newline after it. Therefore, you need two calls to `gets` because the first call only sees `'\n'` while the second sees your actual data.

To fix this, I'd recommend that you use gets to read the full line when you get the operation, and then use sscanf to get the operation.

For example:

```
printMenu();

gets(str)
sscanf(str, "%d", &operation);

switch (operation) {
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is after your first `scanf()` is that there's still data lingering in the input buffer (any form of whitespace that delimits things, usually a return) and when you call the next `gets()` it returns immediately because it read the "enter" you hit after typing in a number.
In order to solve this, you'll need to flush the input buffer.  This is good practice especially when switching between reading individual character words and sentences.  Here's a small snippet I found from another thread that may help you (this would go after your `scanf()`):

`while (getchar() != EOF);`
What it does is continually read characters out of the input buffer until none are left.  This may not be the best solutions for all situations but it should be enough to help you through this assignment.

Comment: Wouldn't `while (getchar() != '\n');` be a bit closer to what is necessary here?